# get position of element in every position change automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know offset() and position() tracks the position of an element but what about tracking it automatically on every position change?

```
<li id="liText"></li>
```

so it has a position change on interval which is made by X, but since I can't change the X's code I but need the left position of the element li on that particular interval

Even tried using

```
$("#liText").bind("reposition",function(){
   alert(1);
});
```

But no luck

Thanks

Comment: It's not totally clear what you want to do.  You can get these positions whenever you want them.  Perhaps bind a function to get this info to whatever is moving the elements?  `$(window).scroll()` etc.?

Comment: What's the actual question?

Comment: @richieahb simone can you check the my edits

Comment: Normally you would have control over X so there is no event handler for checking when an element moves as the movement would be generated by another event handler.  You should see if you could replicate or manipulate X.  Otherwise amin's answer is the only approach that will work.

Answer (score 0):

Put your code just in Timer Function Which using SetInterval
to check the position of element in page evry 10 milisecond for example

```
    <script>
setInterval(function(){var p = $( "p.myparageraph" );
var offset = p.offset();
p.html( "left: " + offset.left + ", top: " + offset.top );
},10);
</script>
```

Comment: it can be random so putting on interval is like having more load

Comment: You are using interval just for checking in evry milisocond....no matter where the elemnt is...try this code :

Comment: setInterval is executed on every interval, its a way of doing things but not good way I guess

Comment: For an Auto Event You must check the element always...and that way is this way....